# Reproduce the GBE journal latex template

Tags: packages, templates, embedding

I have been trying to run the latex template of the GBE journal without success. I am not sure if their template is really complicated or I am just missing something. I am using sharelatex and I downloaded their template here: https://academic.oup.com/DocumentLibrary/GBE/GBE_TeX_template.zip

Thus, I setup a project uploading one of the zip files inside the `GBE_TeX_template.zip`. The project is available here: https://www.sharelatex.com/2414463316ctfcxpwdtrmw

The pdf is completely out of frame and the project has tons of errors. Usually, latex templates from journals are easy to setup, but this one apparently need something else. They say something about:

> select the option "embed all fonts" (or equivalent)

However, I was unable to figure that out. I would be glad for any help to see what I am missing in here.

Comment: That's a pretty hideous example `.tex` file, and including (potentially out of date) copies of standard LaTeX packages isn't a good sign.  I'd get in touch with the journal for assistance, as they apparently want you to use this mess they ought to know how to get it to work.

Comment: Seems it was built to be compatible with BaKoMa TeX using some odd encoding known only to the author and Symbol fonts from about 10 years ago. So I am giving up for now and suggest there are many other current OUP related templates on Overleaf. see https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/oup