# Texmaker. File not found when opening a journal .tex template. Problem with encoding

Tags: texmaker, input-encodings

I am trying to compile this Latex template from Genome biology and evolution using Texmaker in a Macbook Pro:

https://academic.oup.com/DocumentLibrary/GBE/GBE_TeX_template.zip

However, when I try to compile the sample.tex file I get:

"It seems that this file cannot be correctly decoded with the default encoding setting (UTF-8)". It suggests me to use ISO-8859-1. I choose that option and then I get:

"File not found"

I tried to use the "convert to unicode" option in the tools option from Texmaker, as suggested by another post, without success.

Which encoding option should I use?

Any suggestion is very welcome !

Comment: Duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420477/reproduce-the-gbe-journal-latex-template and having tried this <quote>template<unquote> have to agree that without any of the promised documentation it appears worthless to a fresh user as its a nest of more than three different "samples" with NO explanation as to why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the above archive and tried to compile sample.tex on a MacBook Pro myself without success. The file sample.tex is coded in UTF-8 but contains invisible characters (e.g. UTF-8 0092) that are not compatible with LaTeX.

Unfortunately that means, you have to compile sample.tex, note the line of the first offending character, go to that line and erase and replace every " " and linefeed in that line. This has to be repeated with every line containing bad characters.

I recommend TeXShop for the compiling task, as for me it seems easier to jump from the TeXShop console to the offending line. But that might be, because I am more used to TeXShop.

If that task seem to tedious, I recommend giving BBEdit a try. It has powerful tools for text display and for search and replace tasks across multiple files.

With kind reagrds

Christoph Lakenberg

Comment: 0092 = private use two = a form of ' (a type of right single quote) 0093 is the left quote etc. the point above is that its not viewable since it is in the range for control characters and if that's wrong what else is among the three files called sample.tex?